# Error on creating news archive on contao 3.5.16

Tags: contao

If anyone familiar with contao,
I got a default contao error page when I try to create a news archive, I have check the log and nothing is wrong. Do I need add the news module first?

P.S I am newbie contao user, as a client only asked me to resolve this problem.

Last error log :

```
[12-Jan-2017 12:46:29 GMT] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Query error: Unknown column 'master' in 'where clause' (SELECT id, title 
                FROM tl_news_archive 
                WHERE jumpTo IN (315) AND master=0 
                ORDER BY title)' thrown in /homepages/19/d124359810/htdocs/2016/system/modules/core/library/Contao/Database/Statement.php on line 295
```

I use 2 languages for the website with language extension. 
I wonder if it has something to do with the language setting of main archive, because it somehow tells the error of unknown "master"

this is the screenshot of the interface when I tried to create a news archive. 
[Image : create new news archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aslwz.png)

Comment: The Contao Error page tells you to look into `/system/logs/error.log`, does it not?

Comment: yes, exactly. It tells me to check the error log, any experience with this?

Comment: I've added the error log on my question @fritzmg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is missing a column from the `changelanguage` extension. If you still have this extension installed, simply log into the Contao Install Tool and execute a database update.

Comment: Would it be possible to updating manually by adding the master table from phpmyadmin? 
or there's no way but update database using the install tool?

Comment: You can update the database via the Install Tool or via the Extension Repository. From your initial post I guess you have access to both of those things, since the error only occurs when creating a news archive?

Comment: It happens not only for news archive but also for creating feeds and calendar unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, then simply make a database update via the Contao backend or the Install Tool and you should be fine ;)

Comment: I use the install tool to update but unfortunately this is what I have, after running the update : 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception Exception with message Query error: Duplicate entry '5311731150a4248ce922b13ea84cd792-205' for key 'checksum_pid' (ALTER TABLE `tl_search` ADD UNIQUE KEY `checksum_pid` (`checksum`, `pid`);) thrown in system/modules/core/library/Contao/Database/Statement.php on line 295
#0 system/modules/core/library/Contao/Database.php(207): Contao\Database\Statement->query('ALTER TABLE `tl...')
#1 system/modules/core/controllers/BackendInstall.php(616): ..............

Comment: When I tried to run the database update via backend it is also the same, showing the error with the indication to check the system log

Comment: I run the update with only selecting the creation of news and archive with master table and it works now. Thank you @fritzmg ! now on to another issues :D

Comment: Regarding the `Duplicate entry` error: simply purge the search cache in the maintenance section of the backend. Then run the database update again.